# Implement variable waited for loop in Python

Tags: python, django, multithreading

Consider I want to implement the following logic:

```
def fetch_only_once(ids: List[Thing]):
    # lookup every id every 10s
    # lookup(ids[0])
    # wait 10s
    # lookup(ids[1])
    # wait 10s
    # ...

    # example implementation using id
    for (i, id) in enumerate(ids):
        threading.Timer(10 * i, lookup, arg=id)
```

Note that these lookup are individual requests to a random server.

The biggest issue here is that the number of threads is in the order of number of elements. Based on my limited knolwedge of python, I don't think the language scales very well with multiple threads, with especially an arbitrary large number of threads.

I am unsure what the right solution looks like here, but here's an idea:

```
def f():
    thread = create_thread()
    for (i, id) in enumerate(ids):
        wait(timer=10) # non blocking
        thread.async_dispatch(job)
```

`async_dispatch` simply dispatches a job on the thread queue every 10s. Some lookups may not finish in time so the queue can stall.

---

I am not sure if there is a construct in python that deals with something like this, but any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked into something like celery?

Comment: ThreadPool will do the job. Celery seems to be an overkill

Comment: @Marat or probably not, because if parent thread, that created a poll & started new threads, dies, then spawned threads will die also (or become zomby threads that's even worse)